# Getting error in PQS finder in R 3.6 version

Tags: r

I am running this code

```
sub <- read.delim(file="15-cancers-genes-data-insert", sep="\t", header=FALSE)
dna <-as(sub$V1, "DNAStringSet")
for (i in 1:length(dna)) {
   dna1 <-as.character(dna[i])  
    dna2 <- DNAString(dna1) 

    pqs <-pqsfinder(dna2, strand="*", overlapping=FALSE, max_len = 30L, min_score = 26L,run_min_len = 3L, run_max_len = 4L, loop_min_len = 1L,                  loop_max_len = 10L, max_bulges = 0L, max_mismatches = 0L,      max_defects = 0L, tetrad_bonus = 40L, bulge_penalty = 20L,                   mismatch_penalty = 28L, loop_mean_factor = 6.6, loop_mean_exponent = 0.8,run_re = "G{1,10}.{0,9}G{1,10}", custom_scoring_fn = NULL,            use_default_scoring = TRUE, verbose = FALSE)
    if (!is.null(unlist(pqs)))
    {
        dss <-as(pqs, "DNAStringSet")
        dss.df <- as.data.frame (dss)
        row.names(dss.df)
        gr <- as(pqs, "GRanges" )
        gr.df <- as.data.frame (gr)
        row.names(gr.df)
        result <- cbind(sub[i,],gr.df,dss.df)
        write.table(result, file="GQ-result", quote=F, sep="\t", row.names=F, col.names=F,append=T)

    } else 
    { write.table(sub[i,], file="GQ-result", quote=F, sep="\t", row.names=F, col.names=F,append=T)} }
```

Getting this error:

```
Search status: finished              
Searching on antisense strand...
Search status: finished              
Error in S4Vectors:::normalize_names_replacement_value(value, x) : 
  attempt to set too many names (1) on GroupedIRanges object of length 0
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded.
```

When there is no GQ in PQS object it enters in the if statement (Logically it should not enter), it gives us an error. It was running well with R version 3.4 but now on version 3.6 it's not working.

Anyone can suggest where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following for your if statement:

```
if (length(pqs@elementMetadata@listData[["score"]]) > 0)
```

This is only TRUE when you find a G4.